# dynamic controls javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```
<input type='text' class='textbox numbers_only deny_decimal pdt_qty' maxlength='6' style='float:left; width:70%' value='" + qty + "'>
```

I create the above control using javascript(if i press a button), but I can enter non-numeric value in the text box. ( I have written code to restrict user to enter non-numeric values). But it does  not work only for the control i created dynamically? :(

Comment: How do you restrict it on the other elements? It doesn't seem like this input has any event attached to it..

Answer (score 1):

You must add more details on how you create this control and how you attach the restrictions to the control.

It seems that you are doing a document.write, it's better create a DOM element as:

```
var control = document.createElement("input");
control.setAttribute(...);
```

and so on.

Comment: Ok. Then how can i place the created control inside a table cell :(

Comment: You can get the td element for example by id :

var td = document.getElementById("mycontrolcell")

then you can append the control element:

td.appendChild(control);